# Pandas long to wide with desired output

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe below:

```
# df
COL1    COL2    Frequency
A       XXXX    1022919
A       YYYY    224847
```

I know how to reshape to wide format.

```
df.pivot_table(index=["COL1"],columns='COL2',values='Frequency')
```

I got this:
[image]

However, is it possible to get formatting like below:

```
--------------------------------
|COL1      |      COL2         |
--------------------------------
|Frequency |  XXXX   |   YYYY  |
--------------------------------
|A         | 1022919 |  224847 |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear which things are data and which things are column/index labels in your shown output.

Comment: So the "Col2" values become the "Frequency" row? And the "Frequency" column becomes the "A" row? Why?

Comment: Updated the post. I just want my final crosstab to be shown like desired... not change anything else

Comment: So `Col1`, `Col2`, `Frequency`, `XXXX` and `YYYY` are all column headers/names? _Not_ column values?

Comment: Yes. After reshaping from long to wide, `XXXX` and `YYYY` become header/names.

Comment: @sammywemmy The issue is not long to wide. It is formatting. Please see the post...

Comment: @PeterChen, this formatting doesn't make since in a a pandas dataframe world.  You're going to need to build this a manually from parts of a dataframe.